# Why are connections not getting closed?

Tags: java, sql, database, datasource, resultset

I have a code where I am connecting to db using a resultset and then after getting the necessary values closing the connection in finally block.

But for some reason the query is still running and the connection pool is not release.
Can someone help here.

```
try {
 rsU = dbAccess.query(FasoCommon.sqlUpdatable, params, true);
if (rsU.next()) {
            updatable = rsU.getString("UpdatableFields");
            logger.info("UpdatableFields:: "+updatable);

            }
        }
finally {
        close(rsU, null, null);

}

private void close(ResultSet rs, Statement stmt, Connection conn) {
    if (rs != null) {
        try {
            rs.close();
            rs=null;
            //logger().info("ResultSet Closed : " + rs);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            //logger().error("The result set cannot be closed.", e);
        }
    }
    if (stmt != null) {
        try {
            stmt.close();
            stmt=null;
            //logger().info("Statement Closed : " + stmt);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            //logger().error("The statement cannot be closed.", e);
        }
    }
    if (conn != null) {
        try {
            conn.close();
            conn=null;
            //logger().info("Data Source Connection Closed : " + conn);
        } catch (SQLException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can check my answer below and just to correct you on usage of keyword resultset in this context. ResultSet is the object which is populated on executing the query. Hope this helps. Check this link for understanding more: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/resultset.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was an set object which was keeping the refence to the connection even after closing the connection.Fixing that part resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In finally block, Connection object is being passed as null and even Statement object is also being passed as null.

```
finally {
        close(rsU, null, null);

}
```

Check them and pass these object references, if you have access to them and 
non-null references, pass to that close() method and check.

Comment: Connection object is being passed as null  Statement object is also being passed as null as i am not creating an statement object here.i am passing an sql stmt and passing multiple params using vector params and executing using sqldelegate

Comment: Can you please elaborate on sqldelegate?